# Why am I not seeing PR/MR comments?

Tags: pull-request, merge-request, semgrep

Why can I not see PR/MR comments on my CI platform? I have created my CI config file correctly as well as I have installed the Semgrep app onto my organization. I am able to get email notifications working but not with the others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first way to make sure that you are receiving PR/MR comments is to make sure that your CI config file has the correct rule that allows for PR/MR comment scanning. For example, for Github Actions `on: pull_request {}` rule whereas for Gitlab, you will have to use the `- if: $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_IID` rule. Regarding other CI platforms feel free to look at the [Sample CI configurations](https://semgrep.dev/docs/semgrep-ci/sample-ci-configs/) section of the Semgrep Docs.

The second way is to make sure you are actually *performing an PR/MR scan*. You can be notified this via the run logs/CLI logs. Please make sure the triggering event of the scan is a pull_request and not anything else like the following screenshot: [Image of scan with a push trigger event.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHark.png)

And finally, Semgrep only leaves PR comments on brand new issues which will require changing the source code that is being scanned or re-instating your current project.